# Android Studio's Font is messed up after changing theme

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

My entire studio is like this after changing the theme to dark and changing it back. Does anyone have a fix for this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Editor -> Font -> Editor Font.

If you can't change the font, make a copy of a Scheme and change the font to whatever you like.

[image]