# Android Studio weird letters

Tags: android-studio

Why do the letters look like this? Is this another language or something? I just downloaded android studio and the installer looked like this as well.
[image]

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725695/android-studios-font-is-messed-up-after-changing-theme) solution.

Comment: Doesn't work, no matter what font i chose it remains the same.

Comment: You could try changing the general UI font as per [https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207282615-Why-does-these-weird-letters-appear-in-IntelliJ-Idea-and-Android-Studio-](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207282615-Why-does-these-weird-letters-appear-in-IntelliJ-Idea-and-Android-Studio-).